# Change this's property value when it's already set

Tags: javascript, html, css, oop, dom

I have component object which is a reference to DOM element, but with some other properties too, like "top", "left", "formatters" etc.

I have a "refresh" method in the class of component, which should change its properties. I'm calling the method like this:

```
component.refresh(200,300,'formatter1');
```

and at the body of the method I use:

```
private refresh(top, left, formatter) {
  this.top = top;
  this.left = left;
  this.formatter = formatter;
}
```

My goal is to change properties of component object. The problem is, that when properties are assigning for the first time, it's all well (properties are creating), but when property already exists at the component, this cannot be replaced (properties staying same as before). In other words - it is possible to change some of "this" properties of an element when it is already set?

Comment: Could we see a bit more of the component class code? Specifically, how you defined the attributes (top, left, formatter) and how you defined the component class itself. Is it a proper ES6+ class? (`class component`) or something older? (`function component()`). In javascript `this` can behave in some pretty bizarre and unintuitive ways, you might be running into an issue around `this`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use libraries like React/Redux you should never mutate the data, do you want something like this? If so you usually solve that problem by returning new object with new value so original value don't change, if you change any variable that will hold that original object it will be garbage collected.

So what you need is this:

```
component = component.refresh(200,300,'formatter1');

private refresh(top, left, formatter) {
  return new Component(top, left, formatter);
}
```